# Conversion of SQL Intersect queries with self join operation

Tags: sql, join

I want to convert my intersection queries into self join queries but unable to do that. I am not getting the proper output. Below are my Intersect Queries

```
SELECT id,Name FROM AJOT WHERE MARY =1 
INTERSECT
SELECT id,Name FROM AJOT WHERE MARY =10
```

And my Self JOIN queries are as belows:

```
Select a.id,b.Name
FROM AJOT a join AJOT b 
on a.MARY=1 AND b.MARY=10
```

Comment: you forgot to correlate A with B. Also you can think about the difference in the join predicate and the filter predicates

Comment: Anyway you don't needs self joins here. Why not just `where MARY = 1 OR MARY = 10`? A better example of self join is when a table has a FK to itself, like in a father child kind of realtionship for a person table

Answer (score 1):

You need to join on all attributes, that both subsets should have and explicitly use `DISTINCT` for elimination of duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.id,
       b.name
       FROM ajot a
            INNER JOIN ajot b 
                       ON a.id = b.id
                          AND a.name = b.name
       WHERE a.mary = 1
             AND b.mary = 10;
```

Comment: Also do you think this logic is sound? equal ids means same rows (unless id is not unique) and that means mary must be equal to 1 and 10 at the same time?

Comment: @jean: If `id` is unique that query will return the empty set, right. But so would the intersection, which also includes the `id`.

Comment: Maybe OP made some mistake because the intersection from the question seems useless, never returning rows

Comment: @Jean What makes you think you can determine "mistakes made by OP" from information (e.g. is that Id a PK or not) he has not provided to begin with ?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT Name
FROM AJOT
WHERE MARY IN (1, 10)
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- Assumes not duplicates
```

I am assuming that `id` is unique in the rows.  If it is associated with `name`, then include it in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The semantics of OP's original query are only replicated correctly if you GROUP BY Id,Name.